# Choropleth Map interactively changing style

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

I'm trying to create a interactive choropleth web map with qgis2web, but having some difficulties. I know how to create a web map and make some information pop up as you click an especific feature.

But I also want to change the **Style** of the whole map as you click or put the mouse on a certain feature. The real change would be on the column selected.
An example:

If you put your mouse on "Bangu" feature, the "Bangu" column would be selected and the map shown would be like this:

[image: Bangu map]

But if you put your mouse on another feature, like "Flamengo", the "Flamengo" column would be the selected one and the map shown would be like this:

[image: Flamengo map]

I've thought about using leaflet, but not really sure of how.

Any ideas, suggestions, orientations, advices, informations?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.